# HTML Contact Page Not Sending Email

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Hello**, I've recently been building a **contact page** for my html website and it seems to *not send my message* to my email at all!

It continues with -> [image]

I am a little confused also why its not sending the message, and the default errors don't pop up with saying "this is required to be filled".

Here is my PHP code (sending the message) :

```
<?php
  $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
  $website = htmlspecialchars($_POST['website']);
  $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
  if(!empty($email) && !empty($message)){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $receiver = "MYEMAILHERE";
      $subject = "From: $name <$email>";
      $body = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nWebsite: $website\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nRegards,\n$name";
      $sender = "From: $email";
      if(mail($receiver, $subject, $body, $sender)){
         echo "Your message has been sent";
      }else{
         echo "Sorry, failed to send your message!";
      }
    }else{
      echo "Enter a valid email address!";
    }
  }else{
    echo "Email and message field is required!";
  }
?>
```

Here is my JS code (creating the message) :

```
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
statusTxt = form.querySelector(".button-area span");
form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  statusTxt.style.color = "#0D6EFD";
  statusTxt.style.display = "block";
  statusTxt.innerText = "Sending your message...";
  form.classList.add("disabled");
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "src/php/message.php", true);
  xhr.onload = ()=>{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      let response = xhr.response;
      if(response.indexOf("required") != -1 || response.indexOf("valid") != -1 || response.indexOf("failed") != -1){
        statusTxt.style.color = "red";
      }else{
        form.reset();
        setTimeout(()=>{
          statusTxt.style.display = "none";
        }, 3000);
      }
      statusTxt.innerText = response;
      form.classList.remove("disabled");
    }
  }
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Here is my HTML code before end of my body (linking the js) :

```
 <script src="src/js/contact.js"></script>
```

Is there anything i'm missing? Could it be not linking correctly? Im also sending this using an online website, not locally.

Comment: Do you have valid SMTP credentials?

Comment: Is this code from this site ? if yes then many people have had same issues in the comments section. https://www.codingnepalweb.com/create-working-contact-form-in-php/

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag Yes it is. Im curious maybe its because im using githubpages?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Also, is this in any way related to CSS?

Comment: Have you tried php mailer or some other libraries?

Comment: @Arrow no I am not very familiar with anything else.

Comment: @NicoHaase , It may just be a server problem rather than a php problem. Also fixed the tags.

Comment: githubpages won't process PHP or send email. ["GitHub Pages does not support server-side languages such as PHP, Ruby, or Python."](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)

Comment: @j08691 ill try and get a public host for it? Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: "It may be" is pretty broad. What have you tried to check that?

Comment: Correct, GIthubpages wont suppport your PHP but if your running it locally on your machine you can always use toolheaps test mail server tool **https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/users-manual.html** to test if your code works.

Comment: Even if you had this on a server running PHP, `mail` is a shaky function to use. Except on Windows machines (and PHP running on Windows is less common) mail uses sendmail, which means a mailserver running on the local machine. This is an uncommon setup for web servers nowadays because of security considerations. I recommend looking into PEAR Mail, which supports STMP on all platforms. Then you will need a working SMTP server and you can enter the credentials in your PHP script and get things working. The setup you have with mail, on most platforms, will only work with sendmail running.

Answer (score 1):

Using Githubpages, which does not support PHP. That is the problem.